# Best approach for using external API for authorization with Laravel Auth scaffolding

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-8, laravel-authentication

I need to use an external API to authorize users of my Laravel app. I would like to use most of Laravel's auth scaffolding. Ideally I would not use a local database, but I'm flexible.

I'm aware of a few different approaches - using custom UserProvider, storing users locally, etc - but I'm looking to get some insight from more experienced users. Here are my thoughts:

1. **Fetch all information from remote API, do not use local database.** *PROS*: do not need to sync two different stores of data (API and local users table). *CONS*: Password Reset requires a local DB to store tokens. Security issues storing information in sessions, or speed issues if repeated API calls are needed to keep current with API data.
2. **Initially fetch all user information from API and store in local database.** *PROS*: Can use most of Laravel's built in scaffolding out of the box and use events to manage API. Speed and security using only local DB once authorized. *CONS*: data between API and local will be different and require extra work to keep them synced (I've mapped this out and it presents a bunch of issues)
3. **Some sort of combination of both.** Maybe, post-authorization I store a local token & email in the DB, and the rest comes from the API. *I haven't really thought this thru.*

I've spent a lot of time looking for someone who has already built API-based scaffolding for Laravel, but only found bits and pieces. I would have expected something built-in to Laravel, but maybe this is not a common use case.

Anyone have any insight?

Comment: How did you solve this?